# Auto Image Downloader with PHP Variable

Tags: php

My current code is below.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/png');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Skin"');
echo file_get_contents("http://domain.tld/script/skins/' . $_GET["m"] . '.png");
?>
```

I know the problem is with...
    (' . $_GET["m"] . ')
...but how would that be fixed?

I receive the following error.
    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in ...

Comment: What problem? Please provide more detail.

Comment: You're mixing single and double quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
echo file_get_contents("http://domain.tld/script/skins/$_GET[m].png");
```

You were mixing single and double quotes:

```
 "http://domain.tld/script/skins/' . $_GET["m"] . '.png"
^^^                             ^^^              ^^^  ^^^
open                           close             open close
```

Cheers

Comment: That's a completely unrelated issue.  You'll probably want to accept an answer here and then ask about that question (if you need to) in a new question.

Comment: But I don't know if its a problem on my end. I first need to make sure this script works.

Comment: I've answered your question, _"I know the problem is with...but how would that be fixed?"_.  If you have another question, you'll need to ask it separately.

Comment: Okay, I got it to work now. Ill mark it correct as soon as it lets me now. (4 Min)

Comment: Do you know how I could do the same thing with the File Title? Like when the file is downloaded, it automatically names it whatever the value of (m) is?

Answer (score 0):

You are mis-matching your string delimiters.  Try this:

```
echo file_get_contents("http://domain.tld/script/skins/" . $_GET["m"] . ".png");
```